# Unity 5.0.1 Completely Stopping a Coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, restart, coroutine

Alright so I am running into a slight issue, basically, I have a Coroutine that contains a for-loop. I can call the StopCoroutine and StartCoroutine methods successfully, but of course, that just pauses and unpauses the Coroutine. Is there a way to actually stop it and restart it? My end-goal here is to be able to start a Coroutine, kill it at the user's discretion, and restart it from the beginning any time, also at the user's discretion. Is this accomplishable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "rewind" the coroutine, just call the coroutine method again with the same parameters. If you want to save these parameters, you can use closures:

```
public class CoroutineClosureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    private System.Func<IEnumerator> CreateCoroutineFactory(int someInt, float someFloat)
    {
        return () => CoroutineYouWant(someInt, someFloat);
    }

    private IEnumerator CoroutineYouWant(int someInt, float someFloat)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < someInt; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }

    private System.Func<IEnumerator> m_CurrentCoroutineFactory;
    private IEnumerator m_CurrentCoroutine;

    public void SetCoroutineParameters(int someInt, float someFloat)
    {
        m_CurrentCoroutineFactory = CreateCoroutineFactory(someInt, someFloat);
    }

    public void RestartCurrentCoroutine()
    {
        if (m_CurrentCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(m_CurrentCoroutine);
            m_CurrentCoroutine = null;
        }
        if (m_CurrentCoroutineFactory != null)
        {
            m_CurrentCoroutine = m_CurrentCoroutineFactory();
            StartCoroutine(m_CurrentCoroutine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I eventually came to a similar conclusion.